# apply css properties based on html5 data attibutes

Tags: html, css

is possible to apply some css based on other elements data attributes? For example we have four elements:

```
<span class="aaa" data-value="aaa">one</span>
<span class="bbb" data-value="bbb">
display only if the third element has data value</span>
<span class="ccc" data-value="">three</span>
<span class="ddd" data-value="ddd">four</span>
```

and I want to display the second span only if  the third span data-value attribute has some value.

*I'm trying to do this using css* **not JS !**

**[fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/8ntfZ/107/)**

Comment: No, css has neither a parent, nor previous sibling(s), selector.

Comment: @ovokuro maybe read more careful the question and see also the content ? talking about html5 data attributes here ?

Comment: @David Thomas maybe read more careful the question and see also the content ? talking about html5 data attributes here?

Comment: I did read the question quite thoroughly, and css still has no means of styling an element based on a following element's attributes, because there is no previous-sibling selector.

Comment: @David Thomas and if not why you consider as duplicate ?

Comment: I understand what you're asking. Using CSS, there is currently no way to target the previous element, regardless of attributes etc.

Comment: @ovokuro let's be efficient guys, that is another story but not duplicate ;)

Comment: @mcmwhfy You're splitting hairs. Nobody can give you a solution using CSS based on your markup. If you can change your HTML or are open to JS then you'll find a workaround. Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to apply CSS on an element based on its attribute, but not based on other elements attributes, like this:

```
span[data-value="bbb"] {
    /* some properties, but only for the span with 'data-value="bbb"'*/
}
```

Comment: No, that styles an element based on its own attribute, it doesn't style an element based on its next-sibling's attribute.

Comment: Yeah, I figured later he asked something a bit different, so I modified my answer.